# Brother Printer Visual Basic 10

Tags: vb.net, printing

Hello everyone and thank you for being such great and helpful community. I am currently working on **Visual Basic App (using 10 express version)** to print labels by using **Brother Printer QL-500**. For some reason samples provided by Brother don't work.... any of them and worst part there is no Errors any kind.... now **Brother P-Touch Editor 5.1** works and prints fine. I am using **b-PAC3 Client Component(64 Bit)**, running on **Windows 7 64 bit**. I know some people suggested to target x86 and I did that with no luck its a same thing nothing is happening please see Brother Code I am using below. Thanks!

```
  b-PAC 3.0 Component Sample (Badge)
'
'       (C)Copyright Brother Industries, Ltd. 2009
'
'*******************************************************************
Option Explicit On

Public Class Badge
    Const sPath = "C:\Program Files\Brother bPAC3 SDK\Templates\Badge.lbx"

    '********************************************************
    '   Open and Print a spcified file.
    '********************************************************
    Public Sub DoPrint()
        Dim bRet As Boolean
        Dim ObjDoc As bpac.Document
        ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
        'Open lbx file
        bRet = ObjDoc.Open(sPath)
        If (bRet <> False) Then
            ObjDoc.GetObject("objName").Text = txtName.Text
            ObjDoc.GetObject("objCompany").Text = txtCompany.Text

            'objDoc.SetMediaByName(objDoc.Printer.GetMediaName, True)
            ObjDoc.StartPrint("", bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
            ObjDoc.PrintOut(1, bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
            ObjDoc.EndPrint()
            ObjDoc.Close()
        End If
End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        DoPrint()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to contact Brother technical for 2 weeks resolved nothing still waiting for their response but everything is working now... Not this Badge code but my program if anyone has same issue try installing  **b-PAC3 Client Component non 64** as well and **re-install brother drivers**  somehow this fixes the issue still wonder what is the problem would be nice to know to avoid it on other systems.